# Why I can't use bin_to_uuid(id) in MySql JPA Native Query?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jpa

Whenever I try to use this repository class in JPA/Springboot it cannot seem to find the id column that's passed as an argument to the `bin_to_uuid`. I've specified the mysql 8 dialect in my `application.properties`. This query works just fine when ran against the db directly from workbench/cli. Why can't JPA handle using this function?
Running a normal `SELECT id, name from CLINICS` works just fine however

### Exception

```
Hibernate: SELECT bin_to_uuid(id), name from CLINICS
2021-01-18 23:57:22.231  WARN 6064 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2021-01-18 23:57:22.232 ERROR 6064 --- [p-nio-80-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'id' not found.
```

### Repository

```java
@Repository
@Component
public interface ClinicRepository extends JpaRepository<ClinicEntity, String> {
   @Query(value = "SELECT (bin_to_uuid(id), name) from CLINICS", nativeQuery = true)
   ClinicEntity getClinicById(String uuid);
}
```

### Entity Class

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class ClinicEntity {
   @Id
   @ColumnTransformer(read = "uuid_from_bin(id)")
   @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
   private String id;
    
   private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can correct your query in the following way:

```java
@Query(
   value = "SELECT bin_to_uuid(id) as id, name from CLINICS where id = :id",
   nativeQuery = true
)
ClinicEntity getClinicById(@Param("id") String uuid);
```

and it will allow you to get rid of the error.

But I do not think that [@ColumnTransformer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-read-and-write) usage for the `@Id` entity field is a valid use case.
And I am not alone, see [HHH-9808](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9808).